# Fragment and AsyncTask

Tags: android, rss, android-asynctask, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have got the same problem for 8 days now and i hope that someone can help me, i am working on an application that parse multiple RSS feeds and display them on listview with fragment but the problem is that the UI get blocked for 2 to 4 seconds, and every time the user touches the screen the application crashes.
I tracked the problem and i found out that i had to bring the data asynchronously, which i actually did, but every time i have a fragment, the same problem occurs.
In fact,the fragment blocks when it brings data if it does it from a main thread, while i actually bring data asynchronously, that's why i can't get the reason for the blocking.

This is how i change my code, this is my interface

```
public interface OnTaskFinishedListener {
void onTaskFinished(ArrayList<Article> articles);
}
```

i am getting the ArrayList in the AsyncTask like this

```
public class AndroidSaxFeedParserAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Long,ArrayList<Article>> {
ArrayList<Article> rssItems = new ArrayList<Article>();

public URL feedUrl;

OnTaskFinishedListener onTaskFinishedListener;

public AndroidSaxFeedParserAsync(OnTaskFinishedListener _onTaskFinishedListener)
{
    onTaskFinishedListener = _onTaskFinishedListener ;
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Article> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    onTaskFinishedListener.onTaskFinished(result);
}
@Override
protected ArrayList<Article> doInBackground(String... params) {
//....
    return rssItems;
}   

}
```

and finally i get it here in my fragment like this

```
public class FeedPlayerIndexFragment extends SherlockFragment implements OnTaskFinishedListener{

String url="http://www.whatever.com/index.php?format=feed&amp;type=rss";
ArrayList<Article> feeds;
ItemAdapterArticle lfa;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new AndroidSaxFeedParserAsync(new OnTaskFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskFinished(ArrayList<Article> articles) {
        }
    }).execute(url);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
//....
return view;
}

@Override
public void onTaskFinished(ArrayList<Article> articles) {
    lfa = new ItemAdapterArticle(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), articles);  
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you're using `AsyncTask.get()` call which is actually blocking. There's another solution on this problem which doesn't block the UI thread. You need to define a simple interface:

```
public interface OnTaskFinishedListener {
    void onTaskFinished(List<Article> articles);
}
```

The calling `Fragment` should implement this interface. When instantiating the `AsyncTask` you send your `Fragment` as an `OnTaskFinishedListener` instance as a parameter to constructor. The `AsyncTask` should hold the reference to `OnTaskFinishedListener` instance, and when the work is done, in `onPostExecute()`, you call `onTaskFinished()` on the instance. Now, in the `Fragment` you can respond to this call and use the `articles` parameter to populate your UI components. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the code but ArrayList<Article> feeds in Fragment return null, can you write the code for me

Comment: @user1664332, I can't write code for you, I'm not a freelancer. I've given you the idea of a solution, now it's your job to implement it. If you haven't completely understood the idea please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Could you please be more clear so i could implemnt it by myself, give me steps to follow and i'll try, until now i make my interface and make the fragment implement it and i made a constructor AsyncTask(OnTaskFinishedListener), so now i have two onTaskFinished method in the fragment one dut to the implementation of the interface and the second due to the call of AsyncTask on the fragment and finallt i make call of onTaskFinished() in onPostExecute() of the asyncTask but i have nothing as result.

Comment: @user1664332, Do you pass result of the task as an argument to the method?

Comment: I modifiy my code up there, u can check because i getting hard to undrestand beacause i am new like i am said and i have to fix it before monday

Comment: Thank youn so much, it works finally but i did not make the AsyncTask as inner class